# Proving that nilpotent matrices A and B are similar iff they have the same iterated set of nullities.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

What i mean by "same iterated set of nullities", is that $$\dim(N(A))=\dim(N(B))\\
\dim(N(A^2))=\dim(N(B^2))\\
\vdots\\
 \dim(N(A^{k-1}))=\dim(N(B^{k-1}))\\
 N(A^k)=N(B^k)=0$$

My first question is whether this even is a property of  matrices. I am led to believe it is, since it seems to be the reason that the block-subdiagonal matrix is in its specific similarity class, and that we can create it by having as many blocks as there are strings in the string basis, and the size of each block being the length of the string it represents. I can, however, not find anything about this potential property of matrices online.

Now for my attempt at "proving", this:
one way that we can look at similarity between two matrices $D$, and $C$, is if for any map-basis combination $(t_1, B_1)$ giving $D$, so $Rep_{B_1,B_1}(t_1)=D$, there exists a corresponding map-basis combination $(t_1, B_2)$ giving $C$. One could say that they should have the same range of maps they can represent.  If any map $t$ has a nullity of $l,$ so must any representation $Rep_{B,B}(t)$ have that same nullity, because it vaguely said cannot add or remove extra information just by using different bases. Other way around too, if $N(D)=l$, then any map $D$ can represent must have that same nullity. Letting $A,B$ be nilpotent matrices with the same set of nullities, they must both have only an eigenvalue of $0$. Therefore, there doesn't seem to be any other potential choices for difference between maps being able to represent $A$, and $B$, and they must thus be similair. Extremely vague ending of proof i know.

Is the "idea" of my proof correct, or does it need a more rigorous approach? Also, i do not want to prove it with jordan canonical form, because the block-subdiagonal canonical form is learned *before* jordan canonical form.

Comment: If $N(A^k)=0$, then all the other $N(A^i)$ are also $0$. Same for $B$.

Comment: @Arthur I think the OP intended to say $A^k=B^k=0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I thought about that, and it may make sense, but do we really want an expression like "same iterated set of nullities" to only apply to nilpotent matrices? That seems like an unnecessary specification. Oh well. We'll have to wait and see.

Comment: Your post is not really readable. But it is true that if two nilpotent $n \times n$-matrices $A$ and $B$ over a field satisfy $\dim \ker \left(A^i\right) = \dim \ker \left(B^i\right)$ for all $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, then $A$ and $B$ are similar. To prove this, use the Jordan normal form (more precisely, show that the Jordan normal form is uniquely determined by the values $\dim \ker \left(A^i\right)$, because $\dim \ker \left(A^i\right) - \dim \ker \left(A^{i-1}\right)$ is the number of Jordan blocks of size $\geq i$).

Comment: @darijrinberg might i ask, why my post isn't really readable? For future posts. By the way, while i see know that you can prove it with the jordan normal form, this method is introduced before jordan canocical form in my book. The method used there to find the jordan canonical form is to look at the nullities of $t - \lambda_i$ used on the generalized null space of  $t - \lambda_i$, to get each jordan block.